# linking 2 tables on ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got two tables a vehicle table and vehicleservice table. 
How do I link the two tables using the vehicle tables primary key?

I've got this button which takes the user to the service page passing the vehicle id in the url

```
<%= link_to 'Add Service Details', {:controller => :vehicleservices, :action => :new, :id => @vehicle.id},  {class: "btn btn-secondary"} %>
```

in my vehicleservice controller i've got

```
def new
  @vehicle = Vehicle.find(params[:id])
  @vehicleservice = Vehicleservice.new
end

def create
  @vehicle = Vehicle.find(params[:id])
  @vehicleservice = Vehicleservice.new(vehicleservice_params)

  if @vehicleservice.save
    redirect_to @vehicleservice, notice: 'Vehicleservice was successfully created.' 
  else
    render :new 
  end
end
```

when adding a new service record I want the vehicle id to be hidden so I've put the following in my _form.html.erb

```
<div class="field">
  <%= form.hidden_field :vehicle_id  %>
</div>
```

In each of my models vehicles I've put

```
has_many :vehicleservice
```

and vehicleservice I've put

```
belongs_to :vehicles
```

I keep getting a Couldn't find Vehicle with 'id'=

can someone please help its been a couple years I've used ruby on rails and I've seem to forgot a lot of things!

Comment: You're sending `vehicle_id ` but then trying to access to `id`.

Comment: What is in your `routes.rb`? Do you use nested routes? If yes, you need to change `{:controller => :vehicleservices, :action => :new, :id => @vehicle.id}` to `{:controller => :vehicleservices, :action => :new, :vehicle_id => @vehicle.id}`. Btw, why don't you use named route in `link_to`?

Comment: in my routes.rb I've just got
  `resources :vehicleservices`
  `resources :vehicles`